# Passing information from child component to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

I am using React > 16.8 with function components and hooks.

I got a parent component which manages a component to display items and add a new item. The list of items is at the parent component. The way the items are added are by a "+" button which opens a new modal window (which is a component of its own), and inside there's a form that the user can insert the details of the new items.

```
const registerFormRef = useRef();
<Modal
    isOpen={isFormOpen}
    onCancel={() => setIsFormOpen(false)}
    onSubmit={() => { registerFormRef.current.onSubmitForm(); setIsFormOpen(false) }}
    titleText="Register Tenant">
      <AddItem onAddItem={AddNewItem} ref={registerFormRef}></RegisterTenant>
</Modal>
```

The `AddNewItem` is a callback which adds the new item to the list. The modal has an "OK" button which serves as a submit button. It belongs to the parent modal component, not the `AddItem` child.

The method in the child component:

```
useImperativeHandle(ref, () => (
{
    onSubmitForm()
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const newItem = {
            name: formSettings["name"].value,
            description: formSettings["description"].value,
            area: "",
            category: ""
        }
        props.onAddItem(newItem);
        setIsLoading(false);
    }

}));
```

I had an issue of getting the information from the child component which holds the form to the parent component, since the submit button as I said, belongs to the modal, I had to somehow call the callback from inside the child form. I have used the accepted answer in the linked question above. It works, but the comment says it's not a good practice passing information like that. Is there another way of passing the information from the child form to the parent component?

Comment: Please post all relevant parts of the parent and child components.

Comment: Added childs part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to store the form data in the parent i.e the component rendering the modal. To do that you could define a state and provide an onChange handler to it. Once you do that on any change in input the AddItem component must notify its parent by calling the onChange method

```
const App = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState();
   const handleChange=(newData) => {
       setData(newData);
   }
   const onSubmit = () => {
      // use data to do whatever you want with the formData
      console.log(data); 
      setIsFormOpen(false) 
   }
   ...
   return (
        <Modal
            isOpen={isFormOpen}
            onCancel={() => setIsFormOpen(false)}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            titleText="Register Tenant">
              <AddItem onAddItem={AddNewItem} handleChange={handleChange} ref={registerFormRef}></RegisterTenant>
        </Modal>
   )
}
```